# Count and display number of characters in a textbox using Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, dynamic, count, character

So far, I have a JTextArea and below the box, there is text (Character count:) using BorderFactory. I am retrieving String.length() from the textbox to display character count but it's not dynamic.

Could someone please provide advice or code example as to how to implement addListeners in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So far, I have a JTextBox

There is no such component. I assume you mean `JTextField`. Be explicit when you ask a question. We should not have to guess what you are talking about.

> but it's not dynamic.

Use a `DocumentListener`. Check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#doclisteners) for more information and working examples.